# Prove that $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{\sinh(t)}\mathrm{d}t = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2+1}$

Tags: calculus

In order to prove that

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{\sinh(t)}\mathrm{d}t = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2+1}$$

I thought about writting that

$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

$\sinh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

But I don't really know what I can do then.
If you could give me a hint, I would be thankful !
(Sorry for my Eng.)

Comment: One can evaluate this integral using contour integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(t)}{\sinh(t)}\mathrm{d}t  &= 2 \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\sin t}{e^t - e^{-t}}dt \\
&= 2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\sin t}{1-e^{-2t}}dt\\
&= 2\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t}\sin t\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-2nt}dt\\
&=2\sum_{n\geq 0} \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-(2n+1)t}\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} dt\\
&=-i\sum_{n\geq 0} \left ( \frac 1 {i-2n-1} +\frac 1 {2n+1+i}\right)\\
&=-i \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{-2i}{1+(2n+1)^2}\\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{2}{1+(2n+1)^2}
\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pretty sure there are other ways to get to that result.